# Another polar integral bounds question.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

A plane region $R$ is determined by the inequalities $y\ge0$, $y\ge-x$, $x^2+y^2\le3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3x$. Sketch the region and find it's area.

I have foregone sketching the area and tried to use algebra instead. A bit of substitution with the polar coordinates $x=r\cos{\theta}$, $y=r\sin{\theta}$ yields
$$r\le3(1-\cos{\theta})$$ which should give me $0\le r\le6$, and after inspection $0\le\theta\ \le2 \pi$. Right?

So the integral should be $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{6}rdrd\theta,$$ correct? The book doesn't provide answers so I just want to know if I got the bounds right, I can do the actual computation myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you intended to do the problem for the following areas, unless, as @Andrea noted we have nothing to do.

[image]

According to the plot, we have two evaluate two areas:

$$A_1:~~~\theta|_{7\pi/4}^0, r|_{3(1-\cos(\theta))}^0$$

$$A_2:~~~\theta|_0^{3\pi/4}, r|_0^{3(1-\cos(\theta))}$$

Comment: Oh okay, so my bounds were wrong! How did you find the bounds, please? Please be explicit, I am not good at this :P

Comment: @jamesh625: $y=-x$ can be regarded as $\theta=3\pi/4$ or $7\pi/4$. As it's asked you sketching the plot tells us we have two areas as above. Now decide for the limits.

Comment: @jamesh625:And you certainly know that in polar coordinate we [have](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx)

Comment: Nice answere and picture. +1

Comment: I agree, nice plot, indeed. +1.